# How to print list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, printing

So i'm writing a code, listing square numbers lower than n.
I want the output to be a list. like so:  [1, 4, 9, 16] etc.

```
n=int(input("input number: "))
counter = 1
while counter * counter < n:
   for counter in range(1,n):
      a = counter*counter
      print (a)
   if a < n:
      break
```

I would be very grateful if I can get some help.

Comment: For your next codes, try to avoid having 2 variables counter doing different things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can remove the need for the `while` loop and utilise pythons `range` function to generate your numbers up to `n` and use a `for` loop to iterate over them. you also need to initalise a `list` to store them in before the loop starts. and then each iteration of the loop append the square number to the list.

```
n=int(input("input number: "))
squares = []
for num in range(1, n):
    squares.append(num * num)
print(squares)
```

**OUTPUT for n=10**

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Although this can be simpfied using pythons list comprehension style as

```
n=int(input("input number: "))
squares = [num * num for num in range(1, n)]
print(squares)
```

**OUTPUT for n=10**

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

**UPDATE based on comment from B. Go**

user B. Go pointed out that my answer is printing all the results of squaring number up to the value of N. But the question was actually print all the square numbers less than N. Below code to print squares less than N

```
n=int(input("input number: "))
squares = []
for num in range(1, n):
    result = num * num
    if result >= n:
        break
    squares.append(num * num)
print(squares)
```

**OUTPUT N=50**

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
```

Comment: According to me "listing square numbers lower than n" should stop at 10, not 100... But as LEDIK could fix the code, I guess it's OK!

Comment: @B.Go oops yeah i see what you mean, I read it as sqaure the numbers from 1 to N but not including N. but i see what you mean it should be list all the square numbers which are below N

Comment: I have updated my answer for the solution of print square numbers less than N